# How to make analog servo power off with code?

Tags: python, pi-zero, gpiozero

I'm writing a sample code for my pi zero w and I have an analog servo motor (FS9225M) What I'm trying to do is make it work for a few spins then deactivate it so that I can move it manually with my hand. However in order to do this I read that the servo must not be powered. Is there a way to do this with code alone or do I have to upgrade my circuit with extra components? Thank you for your time.

```
from gpiozero import Servo,PWMLED
from time import sleep

from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory

factory=PiGPIOFactory()

#range: [500μsec,1500μsec,2500μsec]
servo=Servo(17, min_pulse_width=0.5/1000, max_pulse_width=2.5/1000,frame_width=20/1000, pin_factory=factory)

towards_maximum=True
servo.value=0

max=10
min=-10
divider=10

i=max
loops=0

while True:
    print(f"[{i}] servo.value={servo.value}")

    if(towards_maximum==True and i<max):
        servo.value=i/divider
        i=i+1     
        towards_maximum=True

    elif(towards_maximum==True and i==max):
        servo.value=i/divider
        towards_maximum=False
        i=i-1

        loops=loops+1
        print(f"loops:{loops}")

    elif(towards_maximum==False and i>min):
        servo.value=i/divider
        towards_maximum=False
        i=i-1

    elif(towards_maximum==False and i==min):
        servo.value=i/divider
        towards_maximum=True
        i=i+1
        
    sleep(1/20)
    
    if(loops==2):
            
        print("maximum loops reached")
        servo.value=None
        break

servo.close()
print(f"closed? {servo.closed}")

print("finishing")

led = PWMLED(17)
led.value=0.0
```

Comment: find out if the servo has the capability to stop holding its position without a power-off ... your question is unrelated to the Raspberry Pi because you would ask exactly the same question if you were using a different controller, such as an Arduino

Comment: Yes, it is connected to raspberry pi though, should I post a schematic with the pi attached to the servo?

Comment: that is like going to a gardening website to ask about building a brick wall because the wall is being built in a garden